# transcribing a pause smaller then a measure

Tags: notation, transcription

I'm transcribing Cappella music. When sometimes there is a small pause less then a measure before starting again the next theme or further melody. My question is how do I notate such a pause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what either a fermata (*on* the last note of the ending phrase) or a caesura (*after* the last note of the ending phrase) are for.

Comment: Does these two, fermat, caesura good for any length?

Comment: In show music, we always call ceasura "rail-road tracks" because they're indicated with "//"  They are of any length.. and usually rely on cues from the actors on stage.

Comment: Fermata and caesura are of indefinite length.  If you want to be more militant, you can always throw in an out-of-meter measure, such as a 3/8 measure of rest in a 4/4 song.

Comment: I think in choral music (which I what I assume you mean), it's more common to use either a breath mark (a 'V-shaped' symbol), or a pause ('comma' symbol).